# Maximize $\text{trace}(Z^{T}A Z)/\text{trace}(Z^{T}B Z)$

Tags: optimization

I am trying to find $Z$ in the following problem:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{c}
 maximize \hspace{2mm} \frac{\text{trace}(Z^{T}Lb\hspace{2mm} Z)}{\text{trace}(Z^{T}Lw\hspace{2mm} Z)}, \\
 \end{array}
\end{equation} for $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $Wb,Ww \in \mathbb{R}^{mxm}$.
Using the scale constraint \begin{equation} Z^{T} Dw Z = I \end{equation}
And Lw = Dw −Ww , Lb = Db −Wb.(Laplacian)

W(Wb,Ww) denotes the symmetric affinity matrix and D(Db,Dw)
is the diagonal weight matrix, whose entries are column (or row, since W is
symmetric) sums of W, then the Laplacian matrix is given L = D −W.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What are A,B,Z? What do you mean by $Z^\prime$? Over what set are you considering the maximum? You should clarify your question by explaining your notation.

Comment: A B and Z are matrixes.. Z':transpose(Z)..I am trying to find Z..
Thank you

Comment: Are they real or complex? What size do they have? What constrains do you have on the maximum? Your question still does not make sense to me.

Comment: They are real..
Does it make sense now?

Comment: What are $Db, Wb, Dw, Ww$?

Comment: W(Wb,Ww) denotes the symmetric affinity matrix and D(Db,Dw) is the diagonal weight matrix, whose entries are column (or row, since W is symmetric) sums of W, then the Laplacian matrix is given L = D −W.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

See these links:

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~thango/reports/trace_ratio.pdf

http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hongdong/Shen-ACCV2007.pdf

http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/archive/2007/CVPR07_reduction.pdf

http://www.fondation-hadamard.fr/sites/default/files/images/pgmo_2013_bellalij_2.pdf

You'll find some methods for solving the constrained problem of the ratio of traces.